# How to use single component as a new instance with react-native tabview

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created one single screen and i need to display it on tabview with two tabs, because the both tab screens are same so i have created single component for that.
but here problem is that when i am entering some text in textinput that on tab1, InputText and switching on tab2 so for tab2 InputText my last entered charector is displaying,

Please see the Screens first tab having Phone number, and in second tab having email,
but if I enter phone number and switch to email tab then for email it is displaying my last entered phone number.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you most probably using the same state that is causing the issue. if you can share the code that would be helpful to identify the issue.

you can also use this approach to have more control over state.

```
_renderScene = ({ route, navigationState }) => {
switch (route.key) {
  case 'first':
    return (
      <YourScreen
        focused={navigationState.index === 0}
      />
    );
  case 'second':
    return (
      <YourScreen
        focused={navigationState.index === 1}
      />
    );
  default:
    return null;
}
```

};

```
<TabView
    navigationState={this.state}
    renderScene={this._renderScene}
    onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
  />
```